# How to get rtf displayed in Django app?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-wysiwyg

I'm creating an blog app in Django. In a form I'm using ckeditor in order to get the rich text format from the user. Now the data is saved in the database in the RTF with all tags. Now I want to retrieve data from database and display it to the user but unable to do so. In output data with tags is displayed.

my code goes like this.

```
class blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
    body = RichTextField()
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    posted_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True, db_index = True)
    blogger = models.ForeignKey(blogger)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form.html:- form for entry

```
<form method = 'POST' action = "{% url 'blog.views.addblog' %}">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
    {}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <center>
    <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value = "Post"></center>

</form>.
```

This is how I'm trying to display data on another HTML page. Blog is context passed containing blog details like body and title:

```
<h1>{{blog.title }}</h1>
<p> {{blog.body|linebreaks}}</p>
```

how to get data back in rich text format?

Answer (score 1):

well a lot of research. Answer is so easy i was wondering why i couldn't figure it out.
I just had to use safe keyword in following manner.

```
<h1>{{blog.title }}</h1>
<p> {{blog.body|safe}}</p>
```